# Configuring an Eclipse project to run on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse (Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0) has been downloaded, and a new workspace created, together with one new project (Spring Boot starter, maven), which displays in Project Explorer. In order to install Tomcat server to Eclipse , Tomcat has been downloaded and installed locally.

In the Eclipse Servers tag, the following link is selected:

*No servers are available. Click this link to create a new server.*

This popup appears:
[image]

After selecting the Tomcat version and selecting *Next*, the following popup allows the server installation to be specified:
[image]

After clicking *Next*, the following popup appears:

[image]

I am expecting the new project to be available to be added to the tomcat server, but the left pane is empty.

What is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of project was it that you created? Was it a Dynamic Web Project?

Comment: I created a Spring Boot Maven starter project

Comment: If it doesn't show up in the Project Explorer, Eclipse doesn't know about it. Does it show up there?

Comment: yes, it shows in project explorer

Comment: question edited to clarify that

Comment: Spring Boot projects are Java applications with an application class. You don't need to deploy them.